# How to access overridden "super" property in the child constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

What should I do to read the A.name in B.constructor?

```js
class A {
    constructor(options) { // options is just an object
        // here one of the keys just happens to be "name"
        Object.assign(this, options); 
    }
}

class B extends A {
    name; // I must have this property here (can't remove it or move it to A)

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        // here both this.name and super.name are undefined
        // I need to have this.name set to options.name value
    }
}

const b = new B({name: "gigi"});
console.log(b.name); // will print undefined
```

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `new B`. From all we can tell, `A` does not create a `.name` property on the instance.

Comment: You still haven't shown us what value you are passing to `new B` - we need a [mcve]. But if you "*must have the property in `B`*", then write `this.name = options.name` in the `B` constructor.

Comment: Apart from `this.name;` being a syntax error inside a class definition, and your two class definitions being in the wrong order, the code works and prints `gigi`, not `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, wrong copy paste for `this.name` in class definition, I corrected it and the classes order too. I pasted the js code from description in https://jsfiddle.net and it prints "undefined".

Comment: Ah, now I can reproduce. Well the `name;` does initialise a class field to `undefined` *after* the `super()` call. What exactly is the constraint "*I must have this property here*", what's wrong with removing it?

Comment: If you know it's passed to `A` through `options` why don't you simply get it from `options`? In `B`'s constructor `this.name = options.name || this.name`

Comment: The parent class (part of a generic framework) has some responsibilities while the parent class has others; to handle some of the responsibilities the kid needs some state (aka fields) so I end up with this kind of situation. I sometimes have to inhibit/override some values that go to the parent `super({overridenOption: true, ...options)` so `this.name = options.overridenOption || this.overridenOption ` won't work well for that case (when `options.overridenOption` is null).

Comment: I also can't entirely rely on `options` because in fact the parent could set the `name` based on some certain context it finds in those options (aka compute the `name`). I don't want to replicate the `name` computation logic in kid too.

Comment: You need to better define your situation, what you can and can't do. We can't help you without knowing this. For instance can you create an other class? If `A` gets the data from somewhere else, is it random? One idea would be to create a `class C extends A {constructor(options) { super(options); }}` and then in `B` do `const temp = new C(options); this.name = temp.name;` but given your *known-to-you-only-restrictions-that-keep-poping-up* no way to tell for sure if that would do (though for sure we can tell that it's a hack and that you did something wrong before if you need this).

Comment: @adrhc What do you mean by "*the kid needs some state (aka fields)*"? The instance already has a `.name` property (created by the parent constructor), you *don't* need to declare a class field.

Comment: @adrhc Also, if the parent *does* set the `.name`, and even does some computation logic surrounding it, you definitely should just move the class field to the parent class.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I changed to `Object.assign(this, options)` which does the same as the initial code; anyway is not this the focus of the question.

Comment: @Bergi consider that the parent is a 3rd party class part of a framework and I need to extend it; in the child class I need some state but whatever state I use it'll be overridden by the parent with that `Object.assign`. I guess your solution `this.name = options.name || this.name` is the best approach and a custom approache must be taken when more than `Object.assign` is used in the parent to set a specific parent-field which might happen to overlap a child-field. So add an answer with the solution from your comment and I'll accept it (I can't accept the comment).

Comment: @adrhc ... Which kind of additional `options` processing is the parent constructor responsible for? Actually, if one of the tasks of the subclassed constructor is to make sure that every `options` property gets assigned to a subtype, then one might just do that right after the super call ... `constructor (options) { super(options); Object.assign(this, options); /* ... */ }`

Comment: @adrhc Could you be more specific about which 3rd party framework class you're trying to extend? "*set a specific parent-field which might happen to overlap a child-field*" sounds like it will be a constant source of trouble. A design where properties "sometimes overlap" is broken imo. It could be the fault of the parent class or of the subclass.

Comment: It was talking about an iphotetical situation, I know no such 3rd party framework; though I see it possible if the base class is gathering some dynamic configuration defaults which then the children would use.

Comment: @adrhc There's your design mistake. The base class should not gather defaults for the child class. At best, it should provide a method to gather defaults, which then the child class constructor can use, for only the fields it needs itself.

Comment: Btw, hypothetical questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow, since they could only get hypothetical answers.